# Find a cartesian equation of the curve $r=1 - \cos \theta$ with $0 \le \theta \le 2 \pi$

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates, curves

I'm trying to do this problem but I cannot get it. Here is what I have done so far: Start with $$r=1 - \cos \theta \;\;\;\text{with} \;\;\; 0 \le \theta \le 2 \pi$$ So I multiply both sides by r: $${r^2} = r-r\cos \theta$$ Now I have: $${x^2+y^2}=r-x$$ Correct?

Next: $${x^2+y^2}=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-x$$ And that is where I'm stuck. What should I do? Does anyone know the final answer so I know what I am heading for?

Thanks.

Comment: It seems correct to me, I don't think it can be simplified much either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated in the comments, it doesn’t seem this can be reduced any further. It would help to notice that this curve is a limaçon, which is partially why I know you can’t do much more with it.

The curve can be parametrized, however, as $$\left\{
\begin{array}{}
x = (1-\cos t)\cos t \\
y = (1-\sin t)\sin t \\
\end{array}
\right.$$

To read more about equations for limaçons, turn [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lima%C3%A7on#Equations).

Summary of the comments: As a student, you have demonstrated that you understand the relationship between polar and rectangular coordinates, and trying to write this expression as a piecewise function $x\mapsto y$ is absurd.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I may look into that. As for my original question, would it be better form to write it this way: $x^2+x+y^2 - \sqrt{x^2+y^2} = 0$ ?

Comment: @DevHeavy It’s genuinely up to you. If you are uncomfortable with radicals, then that is fine. Is there s particular audience for whom you’re solving this?

Comment: This comes from a long list of problems that I am supposed to solve and turn in. It is a list of about 30 difficult problems (it is brutal).

Comment: @DevHeavy If you could include the exact directions, that would be nice. Let me see if I can develop a piecewise function $x\mapsto y$…

Comment: This is the full question: "Find a cartesian equation of the curve $r = 1-cos \theta$ where $0 \le \theta \le 2 \pi"$ This information comes from a chapter and section in my textbook named "Polar Coordinates."

Comment: @DevHeavy Then what you have should be fine. You’ve demonstrated that you understand the relationship between polar and rectangular coordinates, and you have simplified the expression to a reasonable degree. The trigonometry from there on is absolutely absurd. I’d give you the green light on what you have.

Comment: Alright, I really appreciate it @ChaseRyanTaylor.

Answer (score 1):

Looks fine to me. If you want to simplify it into the form $y = f(x)$ you're going to have a rough time, because examining the graph, it's clear that will take at least 4 different pieces.

Comment: Thank you. Was the way I did it the way you would have gone about it? I'm not exactly sure, but does this actually classify as a cartesian equation? I always thought it would have to be in the form you mentioned, $y=f(x)$

Comment: @DevHeavy Any relation in terms of $x$ and $y$ exclusively is technically Cartesian. (If you introduce $t$, then it’s said to be *parametrized*.) However, what you have thus far is not a *function* that could pass the vertical line test or be plugged into a graphing calculator without a computer algebra system.